# Why is my simple data binding not working?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, data-binding

For the life of me I can't understand why this simple data binding isn't working at all.

First I tried it with the combo box (picker) items, and even though the string list "categories_names" gets populated with values in the code behind, they don't show up in the view.

Then I tried a simple text on a label, which didn't work either.

The XAML file:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="budget.Pages.CreateItemBase"
             BindingContext="budget.Pages.CreateItemBase">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label 
                Text="{Binding Thing}"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                />

            <Picker
                x:Name ="IB_Category"
                ItemsSource="{Binding categories_names}"

                Title="Select a Category"

                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                />

        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

The code behind:

```
public partial class CreateItemBase : ContentPage
    {
        private List<Category> Categories;
        private string thing;

        public string Thing
        {
            get { return thing; }
            set { thing = value; }
        }


        public IList<string> categories_names
        {
            get { return Categories.Select(x => x.Name).ToList(); }
            set { Categories = new List<Category>(); }
        }


        public CreateItemBase ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
            var z = BindingContext; // To check if the BindingContext is right during debug

            Thing = "whatever";

            SQLiteConnection DBCon = new SQLiteConnection(App.DBLocation);
            DBCon.CreateTable<Category>(); // Creates the table if it doesn't exist yet

            Categories = DBCon.Table<Category>().ToList();

            DBCon.Close();
        }
    }
```

Any idea on what might be wrong? Much appreciated.

Comment: does your `var z = ...` test work?  If so, then I suspect that you need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: Yes, it returns "budget.Pages.CreateItemBase". I saw something about that interface, but it should work without that too, no?

Comment: I suspect that you're assigning your binding too early, so that the UI doesn't get notified of the property updates.  INPC will fix that, OR you could set `BindingContext = this;` in the code behind **after** you set your properties.